# iOS, Android で特定のバージョンの動作テストをしたい(Webサービスの動作テスト)

Tags: ios, android

RubyにてWebサービスを開発しております。
現在テストをしている中で、どうもiOSやAndroidで特定のバージョンで、画面崩れがおこっているようです。

すべてのバージョンでおこっているためではないため、私の手元のAndroid及びiOS端末では検証できませんでした。

手持ちのスマホのバージョンをダウングレードさせたくないのと、予算上、検証用のスマホを購入するのも難しいです。

このような中、他に検証する方法はありますか？

今回の問題は必ずしもOSのバージョンが原因ではないかと思いますが、
一つ一つ問題解決のために、OSのバージョンも揃えて検証したいと思っております。

Comment: 実機ではなくシミュレータでよければ様々なバージョンでテスト可能です。MacとWindows、どちらをお使いでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。Macを使っております。私も調べてみてiOSシミュレータをダウンロードできることを知りました。ただ残り容量が少なすぎてあまり現実的でないかもしれません...

Comment: Mac book air 4GB